# What is a pager in mysql more clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, batch-processing

I have been studying mysql from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/batch-mode.html In this page there is a point:

> If you have a query that produces a lot of output, you can run the output through a pager rather than watching it scroll off the top of your screen:
>
> `shell> mysql < batch-file | more`

I have a batch file `bat.sql`. If I run it with or without `more` clause the output is always same:

```
C:\Users\Redefine Webs>mysql -u root < D:\Softwear\mysql\install\data\bat.sql
name    date    type    remark
Tommy   2000-01-02      litter  4 kittens, 3 females, 1 male
Bowser  2001-04-26      vet     needed break straightened
puffball        2002-05-13      birthday        gave him a new chew toy

C:\Users\Redefine Webs>mysql -u root < D:\Softwear\mysql\install\data\bat.sql | more
name    date    type    remark
Tommy   2000-01-02      litter  4 kittens, 3 females, 1 male
Bowser  2001-04-26      vet     needed break straightened
puffball        2002-05-13      birthday        gave him a new chew toy


C:\Users\Redefine Webs>
```

- What is a *pager* in mysql? How does `more` clause use the pager?
- How to use more clause from `mysql prompt`? Trying to do so give the following error:

`mysql> source D:\Softwear\mysql\install\data\bat.sql | more
ERROR:
Failed to open file 'D:\Softwear\mysql\install\data\bat.sql | more', error: 22
mysql>`

Comment: A pager is at the OS level

Comment: @Drew By `OS` do you mean operating system?

Comment: yes, like doing `dir | more`

Comment: @Drew But `dir` and `dir | more` also give me same output in `cmd`.

Comment: I don't know what to say. Here is mine: http://i.imgur.com/Ws0jI2P.jpg

Comment: `more` will page the output if it's more than one screenful.  If it isn't, you see the same thing with or without the pipe to `more`.  It's just another application, not really an OS thing.

Comment: Anyway, looks like the MySQL `source` command doesn't allow you to pipe to anything at the `mysql>` prompt.  The noninteractive command is parsed by your shell, before MySQL even runs.

Comment: Fundamentally, you seem to be confused about `more` is.  It's a command, just like `dir`.  It's not really related to MySQL at all.  The documentation is telling you that there is such a thing, but it's external to MySQL.  This *type of command* is a pager -- there are others, like `less` and `pg`, which perform broadly the same task as `more`.

Comment: @tripleee thnx for explaining.